# Get the correct branch form Solve

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, geometry

I am reproducing the derivation in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350157468_Networking_of_technologies_a_dialog_between_CAS_and_DGS) article (exploration of a family of circles centered on an ellipse).
[image]
[image]
I only need the outer curve, the results obtained from *Mathematica* are more complicated than *Maple*, and it's difficult to simplify

```
poly = (x - 4 Cos[t])^2 + (y - 3 Sin[t])^2 - 1;
eqn = {poly, D[poly, t]} == 0
{x, y} /. Solve[eqn, {x, y}] // Simplify[#, 0 < t < 2 Pi] &
ParametricPlot[%[[1]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
(*result from maple*)
ParametricPlot[{Cos[t] (3/Sqrt[16-7 Cos[t]^2]+4),Sin[t] (4/Sqrt[16-7 Cos[t]^2]+3)},{t,0,2Pi}]
```

[image]
Can I get the results similar to the *Maple*?

Comment: `eqn = {poly==0, D[poly, t]==0} ;
Assuming[
 0 < t < Pi,
FullSimplify[{x, y} /. Solve[eqn, {x, y}]]
]` The solution for $\pi<t<2\pi$ is the same, both equal to whet you have in the document.

Comment: @rhermans It may depend on the version, I'm using version 12.0, can't get the results in the documentation.

Comment: I get two branches, with an unfortunate branch cut on the y-axis, in V13: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiBt8.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to play with the domain of `t` to fix the branch-cut switch (note that `-Pi < t <= Pi` is the range of `t == ArcTan[_, _]`, which may or may not be relevant but was why I tried it):

```
poly = (x - 4 Cos[t])^2 + (y - 3 Sin[t])^2 - 1;
eqn = {poly == 0, D[poly, t] == 0, -Pi < t < Pi};
sols = {x, y} /. Solve[eqn, {x, y}] // Simplify[#, 0 < t < 2 Pi] &;

ParametricPlot[sols, {t, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

Thus `sols[[2]]` is the outer loop.